# how can we set any url to a particular index in Webview

Tags: android, webview

Hope someone can guide me through this.

I am loading some pages one by one in Webview through `webview.loadUrl()`. Let I loaded in total 7 pages say 1.html,2.html,....7.html.And I am at 7th index ie. 7.html
Now using `webview.goBack()`,I return to 5.html. Here ,I want to replace 5.html page with a.html page provided other html pages be the way they are. I mean to say ,

```
Suppose I loaded a.html at 5th index which already had 5.html even if I do   
webview.goBack(),I should get 4.html .And similarly on webview.goForward(),I should 
get 6.html.
```

By default , after I reload a.html at 5th index , webview.goForward() won't work at all.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think you would be better off not using `WebView.goBack()` or `WebView.goForward()`.  Simply respond to each click on your navigation elements by directly loading the page you want to display. It's then trivial to implement your custom back/forward logic.  Trying to subvert the widget's own internal history is unlikely to be productive.

Comment: isn't there any function like setCurrentItem or setCurrentIndex similar to getCurrentItem/getCurrentIndex in webbackforwardlist.Hey can you tell me a thing..does webview.goBack() sends request to server again like that of loadurl or not ? thanks in advance.

Comment: It may and it may not.  `WebView`'s caching code has a lot of problems, and you should generally not depend on it to ever do what you want.

Comment: Suppose,I do implement my own cache .What attributes should I store so that It behaves as that of webview.goBack() or webview.goForward().If I only store url , then it would be equivalent to loadUrl .Also it wouldnot get post parameters and all.

Comment: Ayways thanks for your reply and guidance. I would upvote your answer.

Comment: If you want to cache pages yourself, you need to download it yourself, and then use `WebView.loadData()` to display it.

Comment: its not resolved.I upvoted your answer for your genuine effort.